# Asynchronous validation problem in angular form

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to validate a field called "name" in two steps first syncronous and after asynchronous checking if "name" is used before only after a form submit.

app.component.html

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input type="text" formControlName="name"/>
  <div *ngIf="name?.invalid && (name?.dirty || name?.touched)">
    <div *ngIf="name?.errors?.maxlength">
      Max error
    </div>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="myForm?.errors?.hasTaken">
    This name is already taken
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {AbstractControl, AsyncValidator, FormControl, FormGroup, ValidationErrors, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {combineLatest, from, Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';


// simulation of validation
function UniqueNameValidator(control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
  let promise = new Promise<ValidationErrors | null>((resolve, reject) => {
    const nameControl = control.get('name');
    if (nameControl?.value === 'ok') {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(null), 1000)
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => resolve({
        hasTaken: true
      }), 1000)
    }
  })
  return promise;
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  myForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', {
      validators: Validators.maxLength(10),
    })
  }, {
    asyncValidators: UniqueNameValidator,
    updateOn: 'submit'
  });

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.myForm)
  }

  get name() { return this.myForm.get('name'); }
}
```

But what i get is a calling to the asyncronous validation even if i enter nothing in the input and do not press the button.

[image: extrange behaviour]

How to fix this behaviour and validate synchronous and then after a submit use the asynchronous validation?

Answer (score 0):

just check the length of the input string before calling out to your promise

```
function UniqueNameValidator(control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
  if(nameControl?.value.length < 10){
    return Promise.resolve()
  }
  let promise = new Promise<ValidationErrors | null>((resolve, reject) => {
    const nameControl = control.get('name');
    if (nameControl?.value === 'ok') {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(null), 1000)
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => resolve({
        hasTaken: true
      }), 1000)
    }
  })
  return promise;
}
```

It also looks like you are calling the validator on the form not the input. I prefer `[form builder][1]` for this but...

```
// with FB injected as fb
const form = this.fb.group({name:[null, [Validators.max(10)], [UniqueNameValidator] ]})
```

as a bonus, you could pass the min length value into the validator. You would do that by wrapping your `UniqueNameValidator` in a function. Where you would call it like `UniqueNameValidatorWrapper(10)`